# Which action is faster in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When trying to find the remainder of a positive integer n divided by 10, which of these two actions is faster and why?

```py
print(n%10) #1st method

print(str(n)[-1]) #2nd method
```

Comment: for your reference 1 is better because in a second one internally perform 2 operations first is convert into str than get the last element.

Comment: One question, if I ask you to reimplement `str(n)` in pure Python, what kind of code will you write?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your question. What do you mean by reimplementing in pure Python? @Aetherus

Comment: For example, write a function `myStr(n)` in pure Python. That function should have exactly the same functionality as `str(n)`. You should not call `str(n)` in your function. How do you write such a function? Hopefully you'll find the answer to your original question in your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't care.

In real projects, this difference is totally ignorable because there are just too many things that are much slower than finding remainders, some of which involve IO, and some of which involve sophisticated algorithms.

In your case, you should only consider code readability. The readability of the first method is much better than the second.

Comment: You'd be surprised how long `str(n)` can take for large `n`. Arbitrary-precision base conversion has a high algorithmic complexity, and Python's implementation isn't heavily optimized. Depending on the inputs, this operation really could dominate a program's runtime. `n` has to be very large for that to happen, though.

Comment: Yup. My wild guess is that `str(n)` takes O(digits of n) time, so if `n` is not that large, you can simply ignore the difference. If `n` is big enough, I guess Python would store such big `n` in some variation of linked list, and `n % 10` could be time consuming, too.

Comment: I benchmarked and got amazed by how consistent the time is when calculating `n % 10`, no matter how big `n` is. I guess to determine the reminder, I just need the last several bits, so the size of `n` just doesn't matter.

Comment: Base conversion takes longer than O(digits of n). I think Python's implementation is quadratic in the number of digits. You can do a lot better than quadratic with a more advanced algorithm, but Python's implementation is pretty simple.

Comment: Also, you need all the bits of `n` to compute `n % 10`. You might have accidentally made the same mistake FLming did, where the computation ends up constant-folded, or you might have not used large enough inputs to see the growth.

Comment: I wrote a script that takes an input from stdin and benchmarks both remainder algorithm. The `n % 10` approach seems not to vary that much even the input is extremely large, but the `str(n)[-1]` approach takes much time to run on large `n`.

Answer (score 1):

### Original

A fast way to judge which is faster is use `timeit`.

```sh
python -m timeit '4658746110%10'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0142 usec per loop
```

```sh
python -m timeit 'str(4658746110)[-1]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.219 usec per loop
```

### Edited

Just like comment say, if you write `4658746110%10`, it will be Constant folded to `0`.

In python, we can use dis module to see the bytecode.

```py
import dis

def test(n):
    for i in range(n):
        4658746110 % 10

dis.dis(test)
```

```
  4           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 22)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 20)
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  5          14 LOAD_CONST               3 (0)
             16 POP_TOP
             18 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   20 POP_BLOCK
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

And change `constant` number to `i`

```
  4           0 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 26)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                12 (to 24)
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  5          14 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             16 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
             18 BINARY_MODULO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   24 POP_BLOCK
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

First one is `LOAD_CONST`, secend one is `BINARY_MODULO`. so the code you want to timeit may be like this:

```
python -m timeit '[n%10 for n in range(100000000)]'
10 loops, best of 3: 5.82 sec per loop
python -m timeit '[str(n)[-1] for n in range(100000000)]'
10 loops, best of 3: 20.9 sec per loop
```

Comment: Except that you've screwed up your benchmark. `4658746110%10` just gets constant-folded to `0`, so you're not actually timing the computation.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand "just gets constant-folded to 0". More detail, thanks.

Comment: You think you're timing the modulus operation, but Python precomputes that. The runtime is exactly as if you had written `python -m timeit '0'`, except for a bit of extra setup time (that doesn't get timed).

Comment: Teacher~ You are right:) You let me know the concept of `constant-folding`.

Answer (score 0):

The second one takes roughly 3 times longer. I haven't perused the source, but it is likely because of the type conversion and slicing, while the first is a simple, well-defined operation.

```
import time
def timeit(f, n):
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(n):
            f(n)
    return time.time()-start

def f1(n):
    return n % 10

def f2(n):
    return str(n)[-1]

mean = lambda a: sum(a)/len(a)
```

---

```
>>> mean([timeit(f1, 1000000) for i in range(10)]) #average 10 runs
0.111114501953125
>>> mean([timeit(f2, 1000000) for i in range(10)]) #average 10 runs
0.29976160526275636
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter much, but wanted to know anyways. Even when you perform the operations 1 million times I got a diff of < 1 sec.

```
import time
import random

iterations = 1000000

# method 1
t0 = time.time()
i=0
while(i<m):
    n = random.randint(1,100000)
    t = n%10
    i+=1
t1 = time.time()
print("Total time =",t1-t0,"secs")
print("Mean time=",(t1-t0)/iterations,"secs")

# method 2
t0 = time.time()
i=0
while(i<iterations):
    n = random.randint(1,100000)
    t = str(n)[-1]
    i+=1
t1 = time.time()
print("Total time =",t1-t0,"secs")
print("Mean time=",(t1-t0)/iterations,"secs")
```